# New Field in Sync'd Object not displaying in data designer

Tags: marketing-cloud

We recently sync'd a field to our synchronized data extension, the field is loading in the data extensions view and data is populating in the field but the field does not display in data designer. Because of this we are unable to use it for journey builder. I have waited over 24 hours and even sync'd other fields that have successfully sync'd to data designer.

Comment: Have you checked if this new field has the same user permissions as the others in Sales/Service Cloud?

Comment: @fromero Yes the permissions are all there.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred because this field was created and deleted two times in a short period while the object was refreshing. So when the field was added the second time the relationship record for the object was not registered properly.

Salesforce ran a refresh on there end and this solved the issue.